# R Sapply function seems to produce slightly different values to for loop approach

Tags: r, arima, sapply

I have written two blocks of R-code. I believe that they should both do exactly the same thing - except that one uses a for-loop approach and one uses the sapply function. However, they produce slightly different results. Does anyone know what is causing the slight differences here? Interestingly, both methods produce the same value for the first elements of the output vectors.

**Method1:**

```
set.seed(967)
n <- replicate(1000, 200)
ACF2MA <- sapply(n, function(n1) {
  acf(arima.sim(n1, model=list(ma=c(0.4))), plot=FALSE)$acf[3]
})
ACF2AR <- sapply(n, function(n1) {
  acf(arima.sim(n1, model=list(ar=c(0.45))), plot=FALSE)$acf[3]
})
```

**Method2:**

```
ACF2AR1 <- 1:1000 

for (i in 1:1000) { 
  YMA <- arima.sim(n=200, model=list(ma=c(0.4))) 
  YAR <- arima.sim(n=200, model=list(ar=c(0.45))) 
  ACF2MA1[i] <- acf(YMA, plot=FALSE)$acf[3] 
  ACF2AR1[i] <- acf(YAR, plot=FALSE)$acf[3] 
}
```

Many thanks in advance!

I was expecting the exact same results.

Comment: You probably meant `n = rep(1000, 200)`, not `replicate()`, although in this case it doesn't matter except for a tiny bit of efficiency/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The difference is that you're running the simulations in a different *order*. In stochastic (pseudo-random) simulations, that matters. In the `sapply` case you run 1000 MA sims and then 1000 AR sims; in the loop you alternate MA and AR sims.

Comment: Ah that makes perfect sense. Thank you very much for your help!